# Getting the error message "Mémoire insuffisante" while running a batch script

Tags: memory, batch-file, head

I have written a script which runs as I want on Windows7 in french language. Except that although rare, when the command

```
xcopy /Y /Q /I "%CD%\tmp\regexFile*" "Dest-Directory"
```

is executed, I often get the message

```
Mémoire insuffisante"
```

into the prompt command. Therefore, the file whose name begins with 'regexFile' into the 'tmp' directory is not copied into the 'Dest-Directory' directory.

I understand that it is due to lack of memory (into head). 
But is there a means to fix that?

What surprises me most is the fact I don't get that most of the time, furthermore  the file to be copied is not so long...

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction was to suggest that you use ROBOCOPY, since XCOPY is depracated.  Also, see this http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2007/02/05/xcopy-insufficient-memory/
which indicates that you may have a path length problem and suggests that you use ROBOCOPY.

Comment: Many thanks! it was effectively a path length problem. Thanks also for link to the blog, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What about a bigger hard disc? Or remove some needless files from the `%temp%` / `%tmp%`  folder.